# nifi how to read controller service values from custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

how to read controller service values from custom processor

How to get DBCPConnectionPool connection info(url string, credentials, which have already been configured inside the DBCPConnectionPool Controller Service) from a Custom Processor.

This is what I have so far:

1) In nar pom of my custom processor I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <type>nar</type>
</dependency>
```

2) in the custom processors main POM I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

3) In the custom Processors's OnTrigger method I have the following:

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor DBCPConnectionPoolLookup_SERVICE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
        .name("DBCPConnectionPoolLookup Service")
        .description("The Controller Service to use in order to LOOKUP DBCP Connection Object by connection name")
        .required(true)
        .dynamic(true)
        .identifiesControllerService(DBCPService.class)
        .build();
```

final Map attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put(DBCPConnectionPoolLookup.DATABASE_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, "some_value");

final DBCPService dbcpConnectionPoolLookup = context.getProperty(DBCPConnectionPoolLookup_SERVICE).asControllerService(DBCPService.class);
Connection connection = dbcpConnectionPoolLookup.getConnection(attributes);

The above does not give me the values from the following fields in the DBCPConnectionPool Controller Service:

i. Database Connection URL

ii. Database username

iii. Password

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could get connection from connection pool, but not the connection parameters.

Comment: I totally understand, I am not trying to get connection from connection parameter.  All I am trying to do is read the following field values:i. Database Connection URL

ii. Database username

iii. Password

Comment: officially - no way

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate a little bit, I am a new user of NiFi and not familiar with many obvious constraints related to NiFi.  I just want to understand your rational behind "no way".  Please elaborate a little bit for my knowledge gain.

Comment: Sure. As soon as you are using DBCPService.class just check for source code. https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/dbcp/DBCPService.java And you'll see that there is just one public method: `getConnection()`. That's why "no way" to get user, pass, url, etc. Think about different approach. Normally you don't need to access those values.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you so much!